# making the navbar animate when it gets back in the fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see i made a navbar that sticks to the top of the page as you scroll down and succesfuly animated it with a trick. Thing is i couldn't manage to make it animate when it sticks back to the top of the page. I am using Bootstrap 3

HTML

```
    <nav id="navigation" class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Corex" src="images/logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="shopbar pull-right">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav-shop" class="collapsed"> <i class="fa fa-lg fa-shopping-cart"></i> </a>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#search" class="collapsed"> <i class="fa fa-lg fa-search"></i> </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#" class="active"> Home <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li>home shop</li>
                                        <li>home events</li>
                                        <li>home paralax</li>
                                        <li>home blog</li>
                                        <li>home portfolio</li>
                                        <li>home corporate : v1</li>
                                        <li>home corporate : v2</li>
                                        <li>home corporate : v3</li>
                                        <li>home corporate : v4</li>
                                        <li>home corporate : v5</li>
                                        <li>home corporate : v6</li>
                                        <li>create your own <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"> </i> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Headers <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>
                            <li> <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#uber-menu-1" class="collapsed hover-menu" href="#"> Shortcodes <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Features <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Blog <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Shop <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> Events <span class="main-text-color light">+</span> </a> </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
#navigation.navbar-static-top {
    transition: top 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
    -o-transition: top 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: top 1s ease;
    top: -200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#navigation.navbar-fixed-top {
    opacity: 0.95;
    transition: top 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
    -o-transition: top 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: top 1s ease;
    top: 0;
}

#navigation a.navbar-brand {
    line-height: 72px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

#navigation .navbar-brand img {
    display: inline-block;
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 103px;
}

#navigation li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('#totop').removeClass('colapsed');
        jQuery('#navigation').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        jQuery('#navigation').removeClass('navbar-static-top');

        jQuery('#nav-shop').addClass('fixed-top');
        jQuery('#search').addClass('fixed-top');

    } else {
        jQuery('#totop').addClass('colapsed');
        jQuery('#navigation').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        jQuery('#navigation').addClass('navbar-static-top');

        jQuery('#nav-shop').removeClass('fixed-top');
        jQuery('#search').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think in else `jQuery('#navigation').addClass('navbar-static-top');` maybe causing it,remove this line and try

Comment: actually, removing that removed the only animation i had on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**=== EDITED ===**

Minimalist example: http://jsfiddle.net/julienvignolles/xwNqu/

With Bootstrap, your navigation component have 2 states:

1. `navbar-static-top`: in the flow (ie. not absolute/fixed/relative)
2. `navbar-fixed-top`: with a `position: fixed` and a `top: 0`

The animation is a slide from the top. We simply do that adding a class with a different `top` value and the `transition: top 1s ease` (we can replace `top` by `all` to animate other properties like opacity or whatever).

On scroll up, we remove the class `navbar-fixed-top`. The navbar is no more `position: fixed` but instantaneously in the flow. So, we can't have the hidding animation.

The workarround is to use a third state, like they do in [your example](http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/):

1. `navbar-static-top` (scroll between 0 and 100px from top): in the flow
2. `navbar-fixed-top` (scroll under 100px): we fixed the navbar but we don't show it
3. `navbar-move-down` (scroll under 220px): we show the navbar

Note: `#navigation.navbar-static-top` is not really required, it'll be simpler to rename this rule in `#navigation`.

**CSS**

```
#navigation.navbar-fixed-top { 
    /* … */
    top: -100px;
}
#navigation.navbar-show-down {
    top: 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var offset_stuck = 100;
var offset_show_down = 220;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset_stuck) {
        jQuery('#navigation').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        jQuery('#navigation').removeClass('navbar-static-top');
        // …
    } else {
        jQuery('#navigation').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        jQuery('#navigation').addClass('navbar-static-top');
        // …
    }
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset_show_down) {
        jQuery('#navigation').addClass('navbar-show-down');
    } else {
        jQuery('#navigation').removeClass('navbar-show-down');
    }
});
```

Comment: i just don't get it, i tried using this code but it doesn't animate, nor do i fully understand what you did. i also can't tell how (if it does at all) the body padding influences everything (except the padding itself, of course)

Comment: I created a minimalist JSFiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/julienvignolles/xwNqu/

Comment: i think i understand. so we have the third state which is actually a variation of the fixed state so it can animate it? (this edit worked btw, thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 0):

Off the subject!

When you use the `navbar-fixed-top` component you also need to pad your `body` (look at the big warning):

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

CSS

```
body.navbar-stuck {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset_stuck) {
    jQuery('body').addClass('navbar-stuck');
    // …
} else {
    jQuery('body').removeClass('navbar-stuck');
    // …
}
```